# PyCharm Git Panel View Changed

Tags: git, pycharm

I am just starting to use PyCharm regularly. For the first couple of weeks, when I clicked the Git tab in the lower left-hand corner of the window, I was able to see a panel with a few tabs like Local Changes, Log, etc.

However, recently something changed and my Git panel looks as below. How can I shift it back to the original setup and why did it change?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean!

Try this, find Settings > Version Control > Commit, deselect the option "Use non-modal commit interface" [image: deselected interface option] and apply this change.